# Alternative to fopen()'s mode "wx" for Windows fopen()?

Tags: c, windows, fopen, mode

I've got a basic program that's designed to copy the functionality of bash's cp command. I'm developing a copy for UNIX and for Windows. My UNIX version works fine, however, I'm finding that Windows doesn't have support for the "wx" mode option for fopen(), as in the following line:

`file2 = fopen(argv[2], "wx");`

Is there an alternative way to mirror the wx functionality mode for fopen here?

(wx allows for opening a file with write access, but will return an error if a file with the same filename already exists--meaning you won't override the existing file. See [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fopen-for-an-existing-file-in-write-mode/).

note: attempting to run the program in Developer Command Prompt for VS2013

Comment: If `fopen` can't do it, you may have to use the native Win32 `CreateFile` function with `CREATE_ALWAYS` as the `dwCreationDisposition` argument.

Comment: @AndrewMedico `CREATE_NEW`.

Comment: `file2 = PathFileExists(argv[2]) ? NULL : fopen(argv[2], "w");`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY race condition problem

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you cannot pass "wx" or any equivalent to fopen that will yield a `CreateFile` with `CREATE_NEW`. `fopen` simply does not accept any parameter combination to yield that - it's very limited. You can see the source code yourself for `fopen` in the Visual Studio CRT code base!

However you can instead call `CreateFile` directly. This is probably the best approach.

Alternatively you can call `_open` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx) which will take the parameter `_O_EXCL` which can yield `CREATE_NEW` and thus will cause it to fail if the file exists as you want.

From the CRT:

```
case _O_CREAT | _O_EXCL:
case _O_CREAT | _O_TRUNC | _O_EXCL:
    filecreate = CREATE_NEW;
    break;
```

Comment: Using `_open` with `_O_EXCL` and then [`_fdopen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dye30d82.aspx) should be fine... That way the standard file output functions can be used still instead of the `_write` primitive.